# How to place a figure in page margin beside a mdframe?

Tags: environments, margins

In my text I would like to use some icons in the page margin to label element types, e.g., an example or a theorem. The following picture illustrates this:

[image]

My text is double-sided, so I would like to place the icon automatically on the "correct" side, which is the outer side. I would like the colored box to be aligned vertically centered beside the gray box and horizontally centered in the page margin. For the box I would use the mdframed package. What would be an approach to achieve this?

Here is my MWE, of which I would like to extend the `environment` definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{exampleBorder}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\raggedright}
    \begin{mdframed}[
        outerlinewidth=0,
        skipbelow=5pt,
        skipabove=5pt,
        innertopmargin=8pt,
        innerbottommargin=8pt,
        innerleftmargin=8pt,
        innerrightmargin=8pt,
        linecolor=exampleBorder]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum, 
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{example}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example. 
\end{example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum, 
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: thank you for asking this question.  you have just made it unnecessary for me to ask nearly the same thing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are welcome :-) Have you up voted the question already?

Comment: oh, absolutely!  both the question and the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `marginnote`.

```
\begin{example}
    \marginnote{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}} ........
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{exampleBorder}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\raggedright}
    \begin{mdframed}[
        outerlinewidth=0,
        skipbelow=5pt,
        skipabove=5pt,
        innertopmargin=8pt,
        innerbottommargin=8pt,
        innerleftmargin=8pt,
        innerrightmargin=8pt,
        linecolor=exampleBorder]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}
\usepackage{marginnote,graphicx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{example}
\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
\end{example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{example}
\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
\end{example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you are using `memoir`, then you can use either `sidepar` or `marginpar` provided by `memoir` without any need for additional packages. But remember that `\marginpar` floats and `\sidepar` doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{exampleBorder}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\raggedright}
    \begin{mdframed}[
        outerlinewidth=0,
        skipbelow=5pt,
        skipabove=5pt,
        innertopmargin=8pt,
        innerbottommargin=8pt,
        innerleftmargin=8pt,
        innerrightmargin=8pt,
        linecolor=exampleBorder]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{25mm}{0.5\baselineskip} %% <---- adjust these.
\sideparmargin{outer} 
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{example}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
\sidepar{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}}
This is an example.
\end{example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{example}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
\sidepar{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}}
This is an example.
\end{example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This is another approach using `tikz`. Here you can get rid of `mdframed` and do everything with `tikz` but as I don't know your use cases, I left `mdframed` untouched. This works with any document class.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands,table
]{memoir}

\usepackage{mdframed,tikz}

\definecolor{exampleBorder}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampl}{
        outerlinewidth=0,
        skipbelow=5pt,
        skipabove=5pt,
        innertopmargin=8pt,
        innerbottommargin=8pt,
        innerleftmargin=8pt,
        innerrightmargin=8pt,
        linecolor=exampleBorder,
}
\mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\raggedright}

\surroundwithmdframed[style=exampl]{Example}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\Graphics}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\marginparwidth]{#1}}
\NewEnviron{Example}[1][]{%
  \ignorespacesafterend
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \noindent 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth,align=justify] (a) {\BODY};
      \node[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,overlay] at ([xshift=2em]a.east)
           {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \else
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
      \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth,align=justify] (a) {\BODY};
      \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,overlay] at ([xshift=-2em]a.west)
          {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \fi     
}%

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{Example}[\Graphics{example-image-a}]
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
\end{Example}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio
\begin{Example}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
\end{Example}%

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio

\begin{Example}[\Graphics{example-image-b}]
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
This is an example.
\end{Example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida dolor vestibulum,
semper eros nec, accumsan quam. Fusce in auctor erat, eget interdum magna. Duis semper odio
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there also a solution without an additional package? Just for curiosity...

Comment: @strauberry: If you are using `memoir`, Yes!. But you can use the old `\marginpar` too but it will come along with default caveats. `marginnote` is better if not using `memoir`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I would pay 50 bounty points for the additional memoir solution ;-)

Comment: @strauberry You are welcome :-) Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: so in a couple of hours I can reward your answer! Another question: do you know by accident, how I vertically center the graphic beside the mdframed box with the memoir solution? In general, the solution works fine, but I would like to define the sidebar in my environment and not within its content. Thank you!

Comment: @strauberry I have added third option which centers the image vertically.  It is in the form you wanted. Please ask for clarifications if needed.